# feed the output of ls command to head

Tags: pipe, head, ls

I'd like to print the first 10 lines of the output of an `ls` command.

I tried `ls | head 10`, which obviously didn't work.

Then I tried `ls | xargs -0 head 10`, hoping that it'd work, but it didn't either. 
(It seems to work to some extent, but the thing prints everyhting on the same line, which is kind of hard to read!)

So does anyone happen to know how to 'grab' only the first 10 lines of an ls's output?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls | head -10
```

or

```
ls | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I thought --format=horizontal would be enough but the column width is then unknown, because you pipe the output from ls to head instead of your terminal. -w (screen width) fixes that.

Try this:

```
ls --format=horizontal -w80|head -n 10
```

I've only tested this using ls from GNU coreutils.